# Regular Expression for Indian Mobile No

Tags: regex

I want to search for Indian mobile numbers in a file. My regex is working fine for:

```
+91-9762897662
+919762654329
09762897652
```

but not for

```
9762809283
```

My regex so far:

```
(\\+\\d{12}|\\d{11}|\\+91-\\d{10,12}|\\+\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{7})
```

Comment: put `+` as optional `(\\+)?` or `(\\+){0,1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating things. Try this:

```
((\\+91-?)|0)?\d{10}
```

This regex is saying "optional prefix of `+91` (with optional `-`) *or* `0`, followed by 10 digits

Comment: What do you mean "it"? Try "displaying" the whole match - ie `$0` or `\0`  depending on what "it" is

Comment: hey sorry that was my mistake, your regex working exactly fine.